# How to "absolutize" href/src values with server rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Let's say I have an element with its `href`/`src` being a root path like this: `href="/abc/def"`.
Suppose I also wrote a function which looks like this:

```js
function absolutizeHREF(href) {
  const URLBase = new URL(`http://${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}/`);

  return new URL(href, URLBase);
}
```

And send the result of it as a property to the template.

It kinda works, assuming `HOST` and `PORT` are known beforehand. But I'd rather have environment-agnostic solution. According to [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_strings_and_url_objects) the `base` option for `URL()` constructor looks like `origin`, so the question is there an easy way to pull its value out of server instance and just plug as `base` value to the constructor?

EDIT: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561135/how-to-absolutize-href-src-values-with-server-rendering/64620613?noredirect=1#comment114279296_64620613) gave me some ideas:

```js
function returnAbsoluteHREFServer(request) {
  const protocol = request.protocol;
  const fullHostname = request.headers.host;

  return absoluteURL;

  function absoluteURL(href) {
    const URLBase = new URL(`${protocol}://${fullHostname}`);
    const newURL = new URL(href, URLBase);

    return newURL;
    
  }
}
```

So the result of the first function can be assigned as a method of the object passed to the template and then get invoked on relative links there. However, it will vary depending on the link, which brings the problem back to square one - different hrefs/srcs for the same content.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need absolute path? you don't need it to show your images. Setup a public route to serve your static files and use relative path:

```
img(src=`/img/${imgName}`)
```

you don't need to set the path like this:

```
img(src=`http://example.com:80/img/${imgSrc}`)
```

but you can put `/` before relative path and the correct host and port will be used automatially:

```
img(src=`/img/img1.jpg`)
```

Comment: After reading [this post](https://moz.com/blog/relative-vs-absolute-urls-whiteboard-friday) I wanted to come up with solution which inserts absolute URLs into `href`/`src` values without depending on development environment. Surely the server instance stores the "origin" values somewhere, it couldn't process requests/responses otherwise.

Comment: @BillerBuilder If you really need to use the absolute url, you can get the hostname using `req.hostname` , get hostname with port using `req.headers.host`, and to get the used protocol use `req.protocol`.  for more info [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) . if this is what your looking for let me know to edit my answer.

Comment: This does seem to work.
Obviously it's for server only, since it requires `request`, but how do you go about absolute links on client-side then?

Comment: It depending merely on the `request` body is pretty cool, but the result will depend heavily on request parameters and will return different absolutes depending on the link, i.e. different protocols or hostnames, which defeats the point of making them absolute.

Comment: @BillerBuilder To get the host name in front-end checkout `window.location`, it's got a bunch of useful properties that can help you. for example `window.location.origin` gives you `https://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @BillerBuilder `req` is dependent to the request of user. If the user makes a request to `http://google.com` the `req.headers.host` will be set to `google.com`, If the user makes a request to `https://stackoverflow.com` the `req.headers.host` will be set to `stackoverflow.com`, therefore you don't need to hardcode your url and the code will be usable for any domain.

Comment: But `req.protocol` will be different for https and http requests.
Also `host`/`hostname` can be different too if the site resolves/redirects from different links, like `https://www.google.com` and `http://google.com`.